# How can I remove NaN values from a dataset?

Tags: matlab

New to MATLAB, any help with this would be appreciated.

I have a dataset that is 1000 elements in 1 column, and most of the elements are numbers but some are NaN's. Is there a way I can, 1. Find them, and 2. Remove them and put them in a variable (or just remove them)?

Would I have to do this the reverse way and find and remove the non-NaN's (the numbers) and store them in a variable?

Comment: Have a look at the matlab command "isnan".

Answer (score 3):

Use logical indexing to extract the elements that are not NaN and then store them anywhere you like. Here's how it works. If x is your column vector containing NaN, `y = ~isnan(x)` will give a logical vector y such that |y|=|x| and y(i) is 1 iff x(1) is not NaN. You can use this logical vector to extract non NaN elements:

```
x = [1 2 3 NaN 5 6 NaN NaN 9];
y = ~isnan(x);   % now y is [1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1]
x = x(y)         % now x is [1 2 3 5 6 9]
```

Logical indexing is powerful and efficient. You could also say:

```
x = [1 2 3 NaN 5 6 NaN NaN 9];
x(isnan(x)) = -1   % now x is [1 2 3 -1 5 6 -1 -1 9]
```

For more information on logical indexing see the official Matlab documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1).

Answer (score 1):

A option equivalent to @sadeghmir's answer:

```
x = [1 2 3 NaN 5 6 NaN NaN 9];
x(x==NaN)=[];

>x
1 2 3 5 6 9
```